# How can I find out the rarest Steam achievement?

Tags: steam, achievements

Having completed the most difficult achievements for a couple of games, I started wondering how difficult the worst achievements can be. One well-defined measure for difficulty of an achievement is its rareness. Sadly, I don't know how to find global achievement stats for all Steam games.

I'd like to know what the rarest single player achievement on Steam is, in terms of

- individual players.
- percentage of players.

As any answer would eventually become outdated, I'm not asking that question per se. Instead, **I would like to know how the rarest achievements can be found.**

A good answer, then, depicts a method for finding the rarest achievements on Steam.

Comment: rareness doesn't depend on how hard to get but rather on what % of steam players own and play the game.  My 'rarest' achievements on my profile are rather easy to get but its for obscure games with only a small but devoted following.

Comment: I voted to close as too broad, because 1. there are way too many games to make a good answer, 2. because the rarest achievements are obviously the ones given to games that have only just been released, and thus are subject to change very quickly and frequently.

Comment: and u might want to take a look at [this article](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2014/04/introducing-steam-gauge-ars-reveals-steams-most-popular-games/) as a way to try and figure out how to do it.

Comment: Isn't this whole honor sort of dubious, since Steam achievements are so easily cheatable?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: The question is not about a specific game.

Comment: @Bora that's not a valid reason to VTC.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to discuss this in Meta, but shortly, any question which cannot draw its boundaries around a single game or a genre of games is off topic in my book.

Comment: @Bora That's not how we've currently set the lines for on/off-topicness. Check [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2148/15643), and more directly related to this question, [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6890/15643) for more info.

Comment: I've answered the question in terms of *percentage of players* and accepted my own  answer for now. There's still no answer in terms of *individual players*, though I do speculate about that, too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The rarest achievement <sub>*(at the time of writing)*</sub>

On **2015-05-20**, the rarest achievement by percentage (with over 0 percentage completion) that is visible in the Steam community achievement lists was ***Escape* in [*Counter-Strike Nexon: Zombies*](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/273110/achievements)** with 0.0001% of players achieving it.

[image: Escape: Escape 3,000 times in Zombie Escape Mode. 0%.]

Note that this information is probably obsolete by the time you read this.

### Technique

Steam Web API v0002 provides an API for global achievement stats per game, i.e. percentage of players that have got a specific achievement.

For example, the achievement stats for Jamestown can be fetched from the URL http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/?gameid=94200 .

The list of Steam app id's is available from another API: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/

Given these it's pretty trivial to write code that fetches achievement percentages for all Steam games and gives a sorted list. However, this only gives the relative rarity of the achievements. To find the absolute rarity, this data should be combined with the amount of players for each game. I'm still looking for a way to find that data, but I'm afraid that might be something Valve considers confidential.

### Example using `bash` and [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

*Note: this takes over a day and currently produces ~17k files that take 71MB.*

First get the list of appids.

```
curl http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/ > appids.json
```

Using this list, fetch the global achievement percentages for each appid.

```
mkdir game
for appid in $(jq '.applist.apps.app[].appid' appids.json); do
  curl http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetGlobalAchievementPercentagesForApp/v0002/\?gameid\=$appid > game/$appid.json
  sleep 5
done
```

Then parse the files with `jq` and list all achievements in a single file.

```
(for f in game/*.json; do
  id=${f//[^0-9]/}
  jq ".achievementpercentages.achievements[] | \"\(.percent) \(.name) ${id}\"" $f
done) > all.txt
```

Now that you have all the achievements in the same place, just sort and read using `sort all.txt | less` or such. There's a lot of achievements that have zero percentage. On 2015-05-20, these are the entries I found such that 0 < *p* < 0.00012:

```
"0.00010054475569631904  98200"
"0.0001009478946798481 ACH_UNLOCK_WORLD_MAP 218680"
"0.00010108494461746886 DLC5 28050"
"0.00010108494461746886 DLC7 28050"
"0.0001046398319886066 AQS2063 273110"
"0.00010847899102373049 ACHIEVEMENT_WIN_SCENARIO_01_DIETY 8930"
"0.000109708787931595 FIRST_SUPER_GAME 262410"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_GAME_FlagWaver 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_GAME_HatTrick 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_GAME_PaintTownRed 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_HUMILIATION_KillJoy 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_HUMILIATION_SirSlaysALot 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_IA_Untouchable 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_VEHICLE_Ace 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_VEHICLE_Deathwish 13260"
"0.00010998825018759817 EUTA_VEHICLE_JackOfAllTrades 13260"
"0.00011104188888566568 IAOnceObjFlawlessDefense 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 Rib1KStare 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibDistAutoRifleman 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM14EBRGripPodBipodQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM14EBRHSSTGQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM249M150MGOQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM249MagpulMVGQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM4ACCFlashHiderQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM4ACCSupressorQual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibM4PMAG20Qual 203290"
"0.00011104188888566568 RibMissionFirst 203290"
"0.00011189774522790685 Chain Gang 212480"
"0.00011189774522790685 Justice Shot 212480"
"0.00011189774522790685 Ninja Skills 212480"
"0.00011189774522790685 Three's Company 212480"
"0.00011796417675213888 Test 239220"
"0.00011801000800915062 lonelyisland 42910"
```

The first item is an achievement for Frozen Synapse whose name is an empty string, and that isn't shown in the [Steam stats page](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/FrozenSynapse/achievements/). Most of the other achievements in this list can't be found elsewhere, either.

The first one that's visible in the human-readable achievement lists is *AQS2063* or [*Escape* for *Counter-Strike Nexon: Zombies*](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/273110/achievements).

### Speculation about players completing the achievement

The API gives very accurate numbers. Since 0.0001046398319886066 is 1/955,659 with very little error, one could speculate that there are 955,659 *Counter-Strike Nexon: Zombies* players and exactly one of them has got the achievement. Obviously any multiple of these numbers is possible, too.

Answer (score 25):

For the rarity of any Steam Achievement I recommend to use this toplist on AStats:

http://astats.astats.nl/astats/TopListAchievements.php?DisplayType=1

This community of Achievement Hunters is strictly moderated and reflects a good portion of Steam's user base. Cheaters are banned regularly and on sight.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm sure an exact answer can be given, too, but this helps in the meantime.

Comment: @dancek It can't. This toplist is as close as you can get. The problem is that you can unlock any Steam Achievement with the push of a button, aka cheating. While AStats bans cheaters on sight, this list can only reflect a tendency, but no absolute value.

Comment: Good point. So, the correct answer can still be given, but nobody can tell if another achievement would be more rare if it weren't for cheating.

Comment: Why am I not surprised that the Jamestown achievements are at the top of that list?

Comment: @HyperAnthony The top ones that say 1 Achiever, are mostly empty. It says 1 Achiever, but those are very often banned cheaters that still linger in the cache. Some achievers that are the only ones are legit though, such as this guy: http://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Achievement_Info.php?AchievementID=50&AppID=205610&SteamID64=76561197978037893 He even wrote a guide for achieving it, don't know why nobody attempted it. (And no that is not me) But anyway, this site really gives a good demographics of Steam Achievements.

Comment: That list only shows achievements which have actually been earned.  [Tales of Maj'Eyal](http://astats.astats.nl/astats/Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=259680), for instance, has literally 100's of achievements which have never been legitimately earned *(and probably never will, given the game's insanely unfair difficulty)*.  Also it only shows achievements for members of that site, which will give a good estimate for the common achievements, but not the rare ones.

Answer (score 14):

You can find out **your own** rarest achievements, but this method does require that you are at least **Steam Level 10** (since that is when you unlock the ability to add 'showcases' to your profile - but correct me if I'm wrong). Go to your profile, click the edit button, scroll down to the bottom of the page, then change the dropdown menu for 'Featured Showcase' to 'Rarest Achievement Showcase'. This will show you the six rarest achievements that you own, and if you hover over them it will tell you the percentage of players who have it.

Comment: I actually thought of this question as I looked at my own achievements in the Rarest Achievement Showcase. It's a nice feature, but not what I want.

Comment: +1, though this does not answer directly it does help and does not deserve the -1

Comment: +/- 0. Not exactly helpful, but it doesn't subtract from the question.